# How to find the length of unsigned char* in C

Tags: c, char

I have a variable

```
unsigned char* data = MyFunction();
```

how to find the length of data?

Comment: You will have to give us some more details on MyFunction(): What does it do? Exactly what does it return?

Answer (score 9):

You will have to pass the length of the data back from `MyFunction`. Also, make sure you know who allocates the memory and who has to deallocate it. There are various patterns for this. Quite often I have seen:

```
int MyFunction(unsigned char* data, size_t* datalen)
```

You then allocate data and pass datalen in. The result (int) should then indicate if your buffer (data) was long enough...

Comment: If MyFunction is supposed to pass a pointer back to the caller (as in the example), the first argument should be unsigned char**

Comment: No, he's passing the length back.  The buffer is allocated by the caller and passed to the function.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming its a `string`

```
length = strlen( char* );
```

but it doesn't seem to be...so there isn't a way *without* having the function return the length.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to find the size of  (`unsigned char *)` if it is not  null terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Now this is really not that hard. You got a pointer to the first character to the string. You need to increment this pointer until you reach a character with null value. You then substract the final pointer from the original pointer and voila you have the string length.

```
int strlen(unsigned char *string_start)
{
   /* Initialize a unsigned char pointer here  */
   /* A loop that starts at string_start and
    * is increment by one until it's value is zero,
    *e.g. while(*s!=0) or just simply while(*s) */
   /* Return the difference of the incremented pointer and the original pointer */
}
```

Comment: The author is asking how much memory is assigned to char* pointer.  Your null-terminated condition does not stand.

Answer (score 1):

As said before strlen only works in strings NULL-terminated so the first 0 ('\0' character) will mark the end of the string. You are better of doing someting like this:

```
unsigned int size;
unsigned char* data = MyFunction(&size);
```

or

```
unsigned char* data;
unsigned int size = MyFunction(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question did not say that the data returned is a null-terminated string.  If not, there's no way to know how big the data is.  If it's a string, use strlen or write your own.  The only reason not to use strlen is if this is a homework problem, so I'm not going to spell it out for you.

Answer (score -5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>  
int lengthOfU(unsigned char * str)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(*(str++)){
        i++;
        if(i == INT_MAX)
            return -1;
    }

    return i;
}
```

HTH