# C: non-NUL terminated array of chars

Tags: c, string, sizeof, strlen

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261431/how-to-find-the-length-of-unsigned-char-in-c) that it isn't possible to find out a (unsigned char *) string length using strlen if it isn't NULL terminated, since the strlen function will go over the string but won't find any '\0', hence a run-time error. I figure that it is exactly the same for string declared with signed char *.

I saw a code snippet that was doing something like `int len = sizeof(unsigned char *);` but, as I understand, it only gives the size of a pointer - word size. Is it possible to use sizeof in another way to get the result or do I have to get the length somewhere else?

Comment: A `char *` is a pointer. There is no termination for this. And `NULL` is a _null pointer constant, which should not be used in a C "string". You might mean ASCII-`NUL` or `'\0'`.

Comment: You mean a string. If it isn't NUL-terminated you'll have to have another way of determining its length.

Comment: Do not only link to external resources. Site-rules require questions to be self-contained.

Comment: There is an obvious reason arrays are not called "pointers" and vice versa. It's the same an apple is not called orange.

Comment: `unsigned char` is not generally used for strings but for binary data (*it's not mandatory but in general ...*), binary data might contain `0` as a valid value hence, it's not possible to use `strlen()` to determine the length of binary data because it is unreliable.

Comment: @Olaf my question is the second section. I only used that link to clarify my meaning

Comment: @iharob: In general it is a good iread to use `unsigned char` for character sets which extend ASCII like UTF-8 or ISO-8859-x. Especially for UTF-8 this allows portable shifting without encountering the usual signed-ness problems.

Comment: @CIsForCookies: My comments were meant to trigger some minor research on your side about the `sizeof` operator. An additional hint: C does not have a string type. It is all convention of some functions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to get the length from somewhere else. A pointer does not include length information and without a convention (e.g. last element is 0), there is no way to tell how long the array is.

Answer (score 1):

> non-NUL terminated string

No such thing in C.  In C, by *definition* a string *always* ends with a null character.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. C11 §7.1.1 1

A *string* is not a pointer.  A pointer may point to a string.  See below for limitations.

---

`unsigned char *s`, `signed char *s` or `char *s` are all character pointers.  They may contain the address of some character or have a value like `NULL`.  As OP recognizes, `sizeof s` is the size of the pointer and not the size of the string.

`sizeof()` can be use to find the size of a string when code uses `sizeof some_array_variable`.  The length will be 1 less than the size is select situations.

`strlen()` can always be used to find the length of a *string*.  But not all arrays are strings, nor do all character pointers point to a string.  See below.

---

`char b[]` below is an array and `sizeof b` will return 6, the size of the array in `char` units.  When `b`, the *formal* argument, is passed to `strlen()`, it is converted to the address of the first element of `b` and `strlen()` uses that as its *actual* argument. `strlen()` uses that address to find the length. The *length* of the string is the count of characters, but not inducing the null character `'\0'`, so the result is 5.

`char *t` below is a pointer assigned the address of the first character to `b`.  Its size, system dependent, is the size of a pointer like 4,8,2, etc. `strlen()` uses that address like above and the result is 5.

```
 char b[] = "Hello";
 char *t = b;
 printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof b, strlen(b)); // 6 5
 printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof t, strlen(t)); // 4 5
```

Below, in both lines, `strlen()` is a problem as that function expects a pointer to a string.  Instead, it receives a pointer to the beginning of a character array (size 5) that does not contain a null character.  The result is *undefined behavior*.  Code may return 5, it may return 100, it may crash the program, it may report differently tomorrow.

```
 char d[5] = "Hello";
 char *u = d;
 printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof d, strlen(d)); // 5 *
 printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof u, strlen(u)); // 4 *
```

In this example, the size of the array is 100, yet the string length is 5.  So using `sizeof(e)` to find the string length does not return a +1 different answer than `strlen(e)`.

```
 char e[100] = "Hello";
 char *v = e;
 printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof e, strlen(e)); // 100 5
 printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof v, strlen(v)); // 4 5
```

Comment: What about "char * p ="abc"; *(p+3)='d'; ? p is now pointing to non-nul terminated string

Comment: @CIsForCookies `char * p ="abc"; *(p+3)='d'` is undefined behavior in C.  `*(p+3) = anything` is attempting to change the string literal `"abc"`.  For historic reasons, `char * p ="abc";` is allowed.  `const char * p ="abc";` is better coding.  Note: a _string_ in non-`const` memory can be made into a non-string by overwriting the null character with a non-null charterer and not providing a subsequent null character within the size of the array.

Comment: @CIsForCookies  "p is now pointing to non-nul terminated string" -- Do you not understand what a *definition* is? As the answer correctly states, if it's not NUL-terminated then it's not a string *by definition*, so your assertion is incoherent. If the memory is writable, then after storing the 'd', `p` points to an array of 4 chars that is not a string.